# Dependent Dropdowns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, dropdown

I used to track our finances in an Excel sheet I made.  I attempted to port the sheets over to Google Sheets and found my formula for the dependent column no longer worked.  I have looked through many solutions the last couple days and many seem to address a dependent dropdown for a single selection on the main sheet and do not address a long list like a checkbook.  I would appreciate any help in create a code to accomplish this.  I have created a dumbed down version of the sheet with only a couple months to make things easier to look at.  I also cleared out most data validations and formulas to hopefully not interfere with any help.

[Original Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I-zogmgN8nrrGp62vrrYmmydvRg7Trv6db5AoPyjGv8/edit?usp=sharing)

[Z..'s No Script Approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MkbmFJxJkm7BrxEJmKUbzBVUhgOKrLMhAt6LwM3Ta88/edit?usp=sharing)

I am looking to bring the items in the CategoryMaster sheet over to the various months sheets.  After selecting a category in Row D of the Jan,Feb sheets have the dependent dropdown limit to only those selections under that specific category.

Comment: your sheet is in view only mode. Please update the sharing settings to "Anyone with the link" -> EDITOR.

Comment: Thanks Z.. I did have it set for anyone with the link but forgot to change it from View to Editor.  Should be good now.

Comment: I added Z..'s sheet to the original post.  It's a great way to do it with no coding.  Curious about other ideas if one wanted to separate out the months on various tabs with a bit of coding.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this using the `January` tab as example is by creating a new tab `DV` with the following formula in `DV!A3`

```cpp
=MAP(January!D3:D92,LAMBDA(s,TOROW(FILTER(CategoryMaster!A2:ZZZ,CategoryMaster!1:1=s))))
```

[image]

And then creating a new data validation dropdown option applied to `January!E3:E92` selected from the range `DV!A3:3`

[image]

This approach is designed to take into account new values that you may enter in the `CategoryMaster` tab. However, with the current structure of your data, we would have to repeat this process for every other tab. So I suggest you to create a single `Master` tab instead, where you input the data of all the months and another `Filtered` tab where you use the `FILTER` or `QUERY` functions to return a filtered subset of the data in `Master`. On the long run it's going to be better to only have 4 tabs rather than dozens.

Comment: Thanks Z.. I added a second sheet to my post with your approach to solving this.  I like the approach but I'm wondering if a full years worth of purchases would be too overwhelming on one sheet.  I agree that having the 12 months plus the 12 DV sheets would be a little much :)

Comment: If I attempt to add another helper sheet for a new month and use the same formula I get a "Formula parse error" (and yes I did change the sheet reference for the new formula).  If I attempt to change the value of "s" to anything else I get the same error.